# Multiple post image, echo url (path of image)

Tags: images, header-image

Currently I'm trying to create a large header (jumbotron) on my website. The large header is loaded as inline css with the following code:

```
<div class="fill" style="background-image:url('<?php echo img url ?>')"></div>
```

I'm using the [Multi-post-thumbnails](https://github.com/voceconnect/multi-post-thumbnails/wiki/Functions-and-Template-Tags) plugin to create metaboxes to upload extra images. The image I'm trying to load is '**header-image**'. The plugin normaly creates the complete  etc which I don't need.

Does anyone know how I can get the URL of the image?

Answer (score 1):

found the solution:

```
<div class="fill" style="background-image:url('<?php $custom = MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_id(get_post_type(), 'header-image', $post->ID); $custom=wp_get_attachment_image_src($custom,'header image'); echo $custom[0]; ?>');"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get the URL for the thumbnail would be:

```
<?php echo MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_url(get_post_type(), 'header-image', $post->ID); ?>
```

Comment: Oh did not notice that this question was like super old =)